# Sony VAIO VGN and Fan Control

Tags: fan, sony

[Control fan speed on Sony Vaio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879322/control-fan-speed-on-sony-vaio)

I have the same problem:

- Ubuntu 14.04, 14.10 and now 16.04 and 16.10
- Cleaned the fan channel
- Under Windows 7 everything is much more quiet

I already asked on ubuntuusers.de and found some others in the Internet who have the same problem  .... but no helpful hints.

:-(

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Have you checked the Sony web site for a BIOS/firmware update? Try editing `/etc/default/grub` and editing this line to read as `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_os_name=Linux"` and then `sudo update-grub`. Let me know if you need more details on how to do this.